# Is there a way to get the PropertyInfo from a accessor?

Tags: c#, reflection

If you have a property's accessor(s), is there a way to retrieve the PropertyInfo to which they are attached to, without going through every property and seeing if the accessors match?

e.g.

```
//This example uses a sample from a obfuscated assembly
public class ObjectInfo
{
    //the property which to get (laid out)
    public int UQIOWVICXJ
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        public int get_Id();

        [CompilerGenerated]
        private void HVKXLIREWQ(int num);
    }
}

//retrieve method
public static PropertyInfo GetIdProp()
{
   var get_accessor = typeof(ObjectInfo).GetMethod("get_Id", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

   return //the property info via get_accessor;
}
```

The only way I see of doing this is by calling `typeof(ObjectInfo).GetProperties(//All 
Prop BindingFlags)` and then, for each info in the result, check if the get method's name is equal to `get_Id`.

Comment: I don't quite understand your wording on this *"Is there a way to retrieve the PropertyInfo of a property if you have its accessor"* can you quick expand on this, what is it you are actually trying to do

Comment: @TheGeneral so, i have the get method of a obfuscated property, like above, but want to acquire the property itself so that i would be able to call the set method.


Note that with each update of the program, the obfuscated names change so i cant just call GetProperty("UQIOWVICXJ");

Comment: Ahh i see. i cant see that there is any other way of doing this.

Comment: There is no built in function to do a resolution in this direction, but you can get all properties, then get all their accessors and search through that list.

Comment: Have look at this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cDCgCO